# Is there a way to connect an external microphone to android, while using internal speakers and charging the phone?

Tags: microphone, usb-c

I want to improve the microphone sound quality while using internal speakers. I also want to be able to charge phone while on the call. Is there a way to do it?

So far I only saw solutions that would require headphones to also be connected to the device.